# Why can't the range of a projectile be calculated as the horizontal velocity multiplied by the time it takes the projectile to fall?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

If I am given an angle, initial velocity, and initial height, I can calculate the time it takes for the projectile to hit the ground by using $-h_0 = v_{0,y}t - 5t^2$, where $h_0$ is the initial height, and $v_{0,y}$ is the initial velocity in the $y$ direction. Now that I have the time it takes the projectile to hit the ground, why isn't the range of the projectile just the horizontal velocity multiplied by the time it takes the projectile to hit the ground?

Comment: Could you explain why you say it isn't, it looks as though that would work

Comment: @JohnHunter Well when I check my work with this method, I end up getting a different answer from the accepted formula which is R = (Vo^2*sin2θ)/g
.

Comment: You should provide the relevant calculations you did and point out where exactly you have doubts.

Comment: The formula is for when the projectile is projected from ground level, if your answer is just slightly larger, it's probably ok.

Comment: @JohnHunter Got it. I actually just went back to a range calculator https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/range-projectile-motion and realized that I was inputing the initial height in ft rather than meters. Thank You!